# How to set default value for all tables column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, database

How to set default value for all tables column in SQL Server?

If it is string it will empty and if it is int in already created table.

Comment: I think your question is too basic...

Answer (score 0):

Add `DEFAULT` constraint

Here is the way to do it:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
id int NOT NULL,
LName varchar(25) NOT NULL,
FName varchar(25),
Addr varchar(255),
City varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Hawaii'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in SQL server management studio, if you have designed you table using the GUI as opposed to creating it with a SQL statement.

To do this (off the top of my head), select the column you are editing, the properties window should be visible (if not i think f4 will open it). About half way down that you can set column defaults.

Comment: Actually, after threading the question after the edit has been made, I think I may have misunderstood. Do you want to set a default on all varchar and int fields database wide?